# How to remove the right space from a bootstrap built website

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have devolopped a [responsive website](http://usefaith.patronempire.com/) with Twitter Bootstrap 3. However i have noticed that there is a scroll bar at the bottom of my screen due to a right space on the page.  Even though i used

```
body {
  margin:0px;
  margin-top:0px;
  padding:0; margin:0;
  margin-right: 0; 
}
```

I still have a right space and a scroll bar under my page as shown in the picture below
[image: Right Margin]

Please **How to remove the right space from a bootstrap built website** ?

Comment: Please post relevant code here.

Comment: not sure but may be because of your image size. or any div taking the space. post the code ! or create jsfiddle

Comment: @AlexM My problem is just removing the right space from the website. Kindly visit the website and note the right space which enables and horizontal scroll. ALL i need is to remove the horizontal scroll. Can you help  ?

Comment: @SanketPatel I have added a link to the website itself where i face the challenge. Kindly check and let me know whether you can help. Tks

Comment: sure i will have a look @ManOfGod

Answer (score 1):

i looked in to it what i think is, its the navigation bar which is causing it.

try reducing the px for nav bar. look at the picture , reduce the px from 1903 to 1980 may be !! let me know what happens

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. The solution is actually a combination of your answer and that of Alex M

Answer (score 1):

First of all, elements with classes `articles_text2` and `articles_text4` aren't placed properly, they create some extra space on the right. For example, you can set them `left: 50%;`. However, I'd suggest that you re-define positions for all `articles_text` elements because values like `57%` and other look like some magic numbers taken from nowhere.

Secondly, you should remove `padding: 0;` from `#full-width` because it breaks [Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). What I can suggest in order to remove left and right padding is to do the following trick:

```
[class*="col-"] {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

It should help.

Comment: It worked in Chrome but not in firefox 47.1. Can you help me solve this with firefox too ? Thank you for your first answer